# linguagem c esta me a dar um pequeno erro e nao consigo corrigir

Tags: c

Eu tenho que fazer um trabalho e esta me a dar um erro que eu nao estou a conseguir corrigir, o erro diz:

> assignment to expression with array type

O erro é no void `inicializarcategoria()`preciso mesmo de ajuda

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAMANHO 60


typedef struct categoria{
char nome[60];
}CATEGORIA;

typedef struct produto {
    char nome[60];
    int kcal;
    int lactose;
    CATEGORIA categoria;
}PRODUTO;

    typedef struct compra{
        char nome_compra[100];
    }COMPRA;

CATEGORIA cat[TAMANHO];
PRODUTO prod[TAMANHO];

void inicializarcategoria(){
    int i; cat[i].nome = nome_da_categoria;
    for(i = 0;i < TAMANHO ;i++);
        cat[i].nome = NULL;
}


void criar_categoria(char* nome_da_categoria){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; cat[i].nome != NULL && i < TAMANHO && cat[i].nome != nome_da_categoria; i++);
    if(i == TAMANHO)
        printf("erro tamanho do array excedido\n");
    if(cat[i].nome == nome_da_categoria)
            printf("ja existe categoria\n");
     if(i < TAMANHO && cat[i].nome != nome_da_categoria)
        cat[i].nome = nome_da_categoria;
}


int main(){
inicializarcategoria();
inicializarproduto();
menu();
menulistacompra();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não se pode atribuir uma string a um array de char em C.

tenta trocar isso:

```
... 
cat[i].nome = nome_da_categoria;
...
```

Por isso:

```
  sprintf(cat[i].nome, "%s", nome_da_categoria);
```

Notei também que você esta declarando`int i` e logo utilizando como índice. Assim certamente vai pegar lixo de memória e apontar para um índice aleatório provavelmente não alocado. Recomendo dar uma olhada nisso.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na linha

```
int i; cat[i].nome = nome_da_categoria;
```

o programa não sabe o que é nome_da_categoria, porque isso não foi definido, se você quiser adicionar a cat[i].nome, nome_da_categoria, faça assim

```
cat[i].nome = "nome_da_categoria";
```

Comment: Outra coisa, para comparar strings, recomendo o uso de strcpy, da biblioteca string.h

Comment: parece-me  que seria `strcmp`

Comment: Desculpa, errei!

Answer (score 0):

Seu código inteiro está com erro:

- `int i; cat[i].nome = nome_da_categoria;`. A variável `i` possui lixo, então o valor dela pode ser -36, 986, etc. Isso causa erros de memória no seu vetor. Sempre inicie um valor para `i`.
- Como sua `struct` usa um vetor de valor, `char nome[60]`, é necessário que se use a função `strcpy` ou `sprintf` para passar o valor para dentro do vetor.
- `nome_da_categoria` não está instanciado dentro da sua função, então sempre dará o erro da variável inexistente. Receba ela por parâmetro.

  void inicializarcategoria(const char nome_da_categoria){
      int i = 0;
      strcpy(cat[i].nome, nome_da_categoria);
  }
- Na função `criar_categoria` está com erro na comparação da *String* dentro do `for` `cat[i].nome != nome_da_categoria`. A comparação deve ser feita pela função `strcmp`. 1 se for diferente e 0 se for igual.

  `&& (!strcmp(cat[i].nome, nome_da_categoria)) &&`
- Nos `if`s logo a baixo o mesmo erro de comparação e de atribuição do valor da sua *String*.

> Obs: Quando for escrever um erro em tela, use `fprintf`, ou se for o erro de alguma função como o `malloc` use `perror`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error de sistema\n");
perror("My Error");
```